# Android studio, making a textview appear on a bitmap inside of an imageView

Tags: android, layout, bitmap, textview, imageview

been struggling with a problem for a while. Basically, I've been wrapping my head around trying to get the most accurate width and height of a bitmap inside of an imageview.

How it is, I have a textview and a imageview in a relativeLayout. The imageview gets a bitmap from the gallery of the phone, then centers it in the imageview and keeps the image ratio when it scales the image up to fit the screen accordingly. My problem is that my textview is supposed to get a random position where that position is on-top of the bitmap. I've been trying to get the correct width and height of the bitmap for some math, but I can't quite get the correct width and height. My text always seem to get outside of the bitmap. Is there someone that could help me with this? It's been days..

```
     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) 
     g.getLayoutParams();
     DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
     getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);


     DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int dpHeight = (int) (displayMetrics.heightPixels / displayMetrics.density);
    int dpWidth = (int) (displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density);

    int widthMin = g.getWidth();
    int widthMax = dpWidth;
    int randomWidth = new Random().nextInt(widthMax - widthMin + 1) + widthMin;

    int heightMin = g.getHeight();
    int heightMax = dpHeight;
    int randomHeight = new Random().nextInt(heightMax - heightMin + 1) + heightMin;

    TextView test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView11);
    test.setText(String.valueOf(widthMax));

    params.leftMargin = randomHeight;
    params.topMargin = randomWidth - 40;
```

Comment: Create custom Image using canvas. It should solve your problem.

Comment: You mean, as in get a canvas, put the picture inside of it, then find some code to measure it since it exists for drawables?

Comment: yes. you will find lots of help as per your requirement.

Comment: Are you sure it is doable if I load the image from a gallery? The Image I get is an Uri, then converted into a bitmap. It's not a drawable...Maybe I'm confused?

Comment: Convert your image to Bitmap. As long as you are getting an image from the gallery, it will be convertible to Bitmap. Forget drawable for a while if it is confusing you.

Comment: I'm sorry to ask, but could you please show me how to get my bitmap on a canvas, thereafter get the width and height of the image? Or maybe point me in the right direction here on stackoverflow?

Comment: Yup, nothing I try really works. It always returns the width and height as 0.